# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.animatePersistence

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, abstract-methods

Getting following error

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.animatePersistence(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator$ItemHolderInfo, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator$ItemHolderInfo)"
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processPersistent(RecyclerView.java:533)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:241)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3607)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1633)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:341)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:685)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6197)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
```

05-09 19:07:57.029 843-843/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
05-09 19:07:57.134 843-843/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
05-09 19:07:57.460 1535-1550/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0

Comment: getting cold. :|

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem,The problem is caused by inconsistent version，In my project，ReactNative by pom depends on the low version of the RecyclerView(23.0.1)，and I rely on the latest version(25.2.0) of the outside，when I open the ReactNative's page，it will crash.

So the solution is keep the same version of RecyclerView.